# HABTM join table with different primary keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a two models 1. `category` primary key is `cust_number` , 2. `product` primary key is `id` . Now i want to make a HABTM relationship between category and product. Here the problem is how to create join table with cust_number and product_id as a keys?

Answer (score 2):

For this use case you want to use [`has_many through:`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) and not `has_and_belongs_to_many`. They both acheive the same goal (a m2m association) but `has_and_belongs_to_many` [is very limited](https://cobwwweb.com/why-i-dont-use-has-and-belongs-to-many-in-rails).

AFAIK HABTM only takes [the `foreign_key` option](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many) which is used to set the foreign key on the join table, there does not seem to be a way to tell it what PK that FK points to.

Run the generator to create the join model:

```
rails g model category_product product:references
```

Open up the migration and change the foreign key so that it points to your custom primary key:

```
create_table :category_products do |t|
  t.references :product, foreign_key: true
  t.references :category, foreign_key: { primary_key: "cust_number" }
end
```

Change the foreign key in the assocation:

```
class CategoryProduct < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category, foreign_key: "cust_number"
  belongs_to :product
end
```

Then add the `has_many through:` assocations to each end:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :category_products
  has_many :products, through: :category_products
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :category_products
  has_many :categories, through: :category_products
end
```

Comment: After done above steps In rails console i have given `Product.categories` , But am getting error like `NoMethodError (undefined method `categories' for #<Class:0x00007fffe51b6d58>) `

Comment: The assocations are added to instances of a class and not the class itself.

Comment: My `cust_number` attribute datatype is `string` , so getting problem when doing migration

Comment: In that case you need to use add_column and add_foreign key to do it manually

Comment: In migration file?

Comment: Yes in the migration use them instead of add_reference

Comment: can you please give example for migration file , if you dont mind.